# CSS width issue on absolute right positioned element

Tags: css, navigation, css-position

I have a drop down navigation that works perfectly when positioned via a `left` CSS property.

http://jsfiddle.net/durilai/nmME4/1/

You can see that the dropdown adjusts to the width of the content, however I would like to position `right`. When I do the width of the drop down will not adjust to the content. You can see this behavior at the fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/durilai/cTSJt/2/

Any help is appreciated, also any knowledge into what is causing this behavior is also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so basically, from what I can see, the issue was being caused by using the element (in this case ul) directly as the selector.

I believe this was interfering with the below ul elements within your CSS. **Simply changing the first CSS rule from ul to your ID (Navigation_Main) fixes the issue.**

Fixed example > http://jsfiddle.net/cTSJt/10/

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The `right: 100px` in `ul` seems to be setting a width of 100px.

If that does not need to be positioned absolute, then use `float: right;` and use `margin-right: 100px;` instead.

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cTSJt/12/**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using div's instead of the unorder list (ul) element. As you are using CSS to striping off all the default styling that makes a "ul" a list element why not use a div to start with. I can't guarantee it will solve the problem but it eliminates unnecessary CSS and you might beable to spot the issue more easily

And in reality shouldn't a ul only be used for bullet point items, in a text document?